# SPFX - Update metadata of current page

Tags: spfx

I want to create a webpart where the user can provide additional metadata to a page.

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve? I guess there can be some issues with updating a page that currently being updated.

I also need to be able to get the ID of the page Im updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed a test now and was able to solve this through the current context.

The following line gave me the ID of the current sitepage.

```
this.context.pageContext.listItem.id
```

Remember that this will not work in workbench, and has to be tested directly on a page.

I didn´t face any issues with updating the page I currently edited as I first thought.